Разберемся что к чему - запятая перед "что"

Там и разберемся(,) что к чему.

Нужна ли запятая?

Да: разберемся, что к чему(прибавить) - два разных действия, сложноподчиненная конструкция..

Запятая нужна. См. у Розенталя:

§ 33. Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения
1. Придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения отделяется или выделяется запятыми <…>.
2. В составе сложноподчиненного предложения может быть неполное предложение — в главной части или придаточной:
1) неполное в главной части: <…>;
2) неполное или близкое к неполному в придаточной части: <…> Постепенно научились разбираться, что к чему (ср.: Поймёшь, что к чему)…


В моем ответе: Запятая ставится в СПП с неполным придаточным изъяснительным, союзное слово ЧТО.   Этого недостаточно? Что нового в вашем ответе?  Никак не могу понять.  Чем неполное предложение отличается от близкого к неполному? К чему это цитирование Розенталя? Грамматический анализ был бы более уместен. Вы хотя бы средство связи указали , чтобы было видно, что это придаточное.  А вот устойчивые обороты следует отличать от придаточных.  Зачем дублировать МОЙ ответ один к одному?  Мы с Тамарой ходим парой уже какую тему.

Sharon: «Что нового в вашем ответе?» === Ссылка на правило Розенталя, которое Вы не привели.

На запятую в СПП нужна ссылка?  Так  никто не догадается, что между главным и придаточным ставится запятая?  Как говорится, без комментариев.  У вас тогда неограниченные возможности дублировать все мои ответы.  Ладно, я разрешаю. Кто-нибудь за вас проголосует в любом случае)  Но вообще вы меня позабавили)

Sharon, я привёл привёл пример из Розенталя, практически дословно совпадающий с приведённым в вопросе Aleksa. Ср.: Там и разберемся, что к чему / Постепенно научились разбираться, что к чему. По-моему, этого достаточно.

Даже много!  Ссылки на запятую в СПП вполне хватило бы. Кстати, грамматической характеристики этого примера вы так и не указали.

Рассказ в трех частях
ЧАСТЬ 1. ОТВЕТ
Правильно: Там и разберемся, что (относится) к чему.

Запятая ставится в  СПП с неполным придаточным изъяснительным, союзное слово ЧТО.

Примечание. Это частный вид неполного предложения, а именно эллипсис.  Эллипсис (эллипс) (греч. ellipsis — выпадение, опущение). Пропуск элемента высказывания, легко восстанавливаемого в данном контексте или ситуации. Эллиптические предложение строится по схеме: подлежащее (что) — дополнение (к чему). У Розенталя § 6, пункт1. Тире в неполном предложении  http://oldrozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93
По структуре что к чему напоминает фразеологический (устойчивый) оборот речи.

Однако в некоторых случаях придаточное нужно отличать от устойчивого сочетания, когда запятая не ставится. Например, у Розенталя:
бери что дают, бери что нравится (= любую вещь)
городит чёрт знает что (= говорит непонятное)
дать чего не жалко (= ненужное)



Данное правило основано на том, что фразеологический оборот не образует придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения и обычно эквивалентен члену предложения. Так, в сочетании говорит об этом где только может выделенные слова имеют значение ‘везде’.
Если же какое-либо из приведенных выше и аналогичных словосочетаний употреблено не в качестве фразеологизма, то оно может образовать придаточную часть (обычно неполное предложение) и быть выделено запятыми: Просторечные слова стали употреблять где нужно и не нужно — ‘везде’; Поставить, где нужно, недостающие знаки препинания — ‘где это нужно’.
ЧАСТЬ 2. СОМНЕНИЯ (конфликт)
А это много-много примеров в Карте слов! И все без запятой, что самое смешное!
Пользователи явно считают, что это устойчивое сочетание. Возможно,  они правы, так что ситуация интересная)
А ведь Грамота говорит, что запятая нужна:
   № 313204
   Добрый день! Вы не могли бы помочь разобраться: 
   в сочетании "понятно что к чему" нужна запятая? 
   По какой причине ее нужно или не нужно ставить?
   ОТВЕТ
   Запятая перед ***что к чему*** нужна, так как 
   это придаточная часть сложноподчиненного 
   предложения. Она представляет собой неполное 
   предложение. См. пункт 2 параграфа 33.2 
   справочника по пунктуации Д. Э. Розенталя.

ЧАСТЬ 3. РЕШЕНИЕ (компромисс)
Устойчивость оборота  определяется в конкретном предложении, и это общее правило в данной теме. Решение во много авторское и зависит от расстановки ударений.
Если придаточное считать устойчивым сочетанием,то можно заменить одним словом: разобраться в проблеме.
В заданном предложении запятая может ставиться, тогда это придаточное, но отсутствие запятой тоже возможно, и тогда это устойчивый оборот. Авторский выбор.
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
Ясное дело, он разберётся что к чему, его никто не сможет объегорить, он хорошо знает, что почём, что ему нужно на самом деле, а что – нет.
К утру следующего дня он, конечно, разберётся что к чему, но будет поздно.
Впрочем, я быстро разобралась что к чему.
Это вначале лицеистки 9 «Г» не разобрались что к чему.
